# How to build x86_64 GTK# applications on Xamarin studio on macOS?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

I have:

1. mono-4.8.0.472
2. Xamarin studio
3. Mac OS Sierra 0.12.3
4. gtk-sharp-2.12.42

I have install Xamarin studio from package. Than I have try to build x86_64 GTK# application, and i can't... I have read that for x86_64 applications i need to compile mono from source. I have delete mono by script and compile it from tarball. So Xamarin studio not working. When I start it I have error message : "This application requires Mono 4.3 or newer."
I try to install mono on different folders: /opt/mono/mono-4.8.0. Then i have try to do this (in mono folder):

./autogen.sh --enable-nls=no --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Git --with-monotouch=yes && make && make install

I also have try to change prefix to "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework" and have the same result.

When I trying to change architecture of project setting I can't add x64
([Select arch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZTsL.png)). Sorry for Russian interface. I don't know how to switch to English.

I need to build x86_64 GTK# applications on Xamarin studio. How can I do this?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: @joanolo, I have edit my question.

Comment: I'd suggest you change the *title* of your question, maybe something like "How to build x86_64 GTK# applications on Xamarin studio on macOS?"

Comment: From where did you read that you need to compile Mono from source? That  content might have already been invalid.

Comment: @LexLi, Here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/.
Quote "The Mono packages published on this web site provide a 32-bit Mono VM.

Support for 64-bit VMs as of Mono 2.10 is only available if you build Mono from source code and install your own copy of the VM. In the future we will ship both mono and mono64 binaries for our users."

Comment: @Dzam, you should inform Mono guys to update that page, as Mono already supports 64 bit on Mac since 4.4.0, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.4.0/

Comment: @LexLi, you are right. I have installed last mono from .dmg and launch 

*.exe file with command
mono --arch=64 some.exe

and it started. But in the Xamarin studio I can't select x64 configuration. I think that is question to Xamarin studio.

Comment: @Dzam you should be able to add a new configuration and  set it to x64.

Comment: @LexLi, where I can do this? I have seen all of page of settings, and not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only working with the solution wide configurations in the screen shot you showed. All this does is create configurations that each project in the solution can use. You still have to set the architecture in the project options, Project Options->Build->Compiler->Platform Target field:

[image]

If you want separate configurations for x86 and x64, then do the following:

1. Open the Project Options->Build->Configurations page.
2. Select the Debug|x86 configuration and Click "Copy" button.
3. Select Debug for the Name field.
4. Manually enter "x64" in the Platform field. 
   [image]
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, and 4 using Release instead of Debug.
6. Select the Build->Compiler page.
7. Select Debug for Configuration and x64 for Platform in the drop downs at the top.
8. In Platform Target field select "x64"
   [image]
9. Repeat step 7 and 8 for Release configuration.
10. Open the Solution Options->Build->Configurations page (same as you showed in your screenshot)
11. repeat steps 2,3, and 4 for Debug and Release configurations.
12. Switch to the Configuration Mappings tab an select Configuration: Debug and Platform: x64 at the top.
13. In the Solution Item list, in the configuration column for your project, select Debug|x64 in the drop down. 
    [image]
14. Repeat steps 12 and 13 using Release instead of Debug.

Now when you select Debug|x64 or Release|x64 configurations, you will be building for x64.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
/bin/launchctl setenv MONO_ENV_OPTIONS --arch=64
```